# How to convert objectid to string

Tags: pymongo, objectid

I want to get the string character from an ObjectId object. I use pymongo.
eg: `ObjectId("543b591d91b9e510a06a42e2")`, I want to get `"543b591d91b9e510a06a42e2"`.

I see the doc, It says `ObjectId.toString()`, `ObjectId.valueOf()`.

So I make this code: `from bson.objectid import ObjectId`.

But when I use `ObjectId.valueOf()`, It shows:

> 'ObjectId' object has no attribute 'valueOf'.

How can I get it? Thanks.

Comment: I had made it with `str(ObjectId)`. It works well.

Answer (score 136):

[ObjectId.toString()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/) and [ObjectId.valueOf()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.valueOf/) are in Mongo **JavaScript** API.

In Python API (with PyMongo) proper way is to use pythonic `str(object_id)` as you suggested in comment, see [documentation on ObjectId](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.8/api/bson/objectid.html).

Answer (score 20):

ObjectId.toString() returns the string representation of the ObjectId() object.

In pymongo str(o) get a hex encoded version of ObjectId o.

Check this [link](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7/api/pymongo/objectid.html).

Answer (score 4):

What works for me is to "sanitize" the output so Pydantic doesn't get indigestion from an _id that is of type ObjectId...here's what works for me...
I'm converting _id to a string before returning the output...

```
# Get One
@router.get("/{id}")
def get_one(id):
    query = {"_id": ObjectId(id)}
    resp = db.my_collection.find_one(query)

    if resp:
        resp['_id'] = str(resp['_id'])
        return resp
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail=f"Unable to retrieve record")
```

Answer (score 3):

In python (Pymongo) there's no inbuilt method to do it so iterate over the result you fetched from db and then typecast _id to str(_id)

```
result = collection.find({query})

for docs in result:
    docs[_id] = str(docs[_id])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `str(ObjectId)`, as already mentined in the comment by @Simon.

```py
@app.route("/api/employee", methods=['POST'])
def create_employee():
    json = request.get_json()
    result = employee.insert_employee(json)
    return { "id": str(result.inserted_id) }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but as the existing answers didn't help me:

Having run

```py
new_object = collection.insert_one(doc)
```

I was able to get the ObjectID with the `inserted_id` property:

```py
print(f"{new_object.inserted_id}")
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the string representation of an ObjectId in pymongo, you can use the `str()` function. Here's a quick example:

```py
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

# Your ObjectId
my_object_id = ObjectId("543b591d91b9e510a06a42e2")

# Convert to string
string_representation = str(my_object_id)

# Now, string_representation contains your ObjectId as a string
print(string_representation)
```

Answer (score -3):

first you have to assign the Object Id value to a variable
for example:

```
let objectId = ObjectId("543b591d91b9e510a06a42e2");
```

then use the toString method like this

```
let id = objectId.toString();
```

Comment: This would only work on JavaScript but assuming one is working with Python then objectID won't have toString(). If using python just do str(ObjectId)