# How to convert ObjectId to string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas dataframe from mongo, I want to convert every objectId to string. What is the best practices to do so ?

```
a = {
"_id": ObjectId(),
"userID": ObjectId(),
"info": {
    "type": "test_company",
},
"IDs": [ObjectId(), ObjectId(), ObjectId()],
"statusId": 0,
"_created": 18563931823148,
"_touched": 17567296847630,
"_updated": 19857296847630,}

df = pd.DataFrame([a])
```

Comment: `df["_id"] = df["_id"].apply(str)`

Comment: Please post `ObjectId()` and its output

Comment: I want something general, I mean most of the time I am not sure which column is objectId, this objectId comes from mongodb

Comment: See this SO answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353627)